# Export to Excel from Destop application using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an application. Please see the screenshot. I need to Export table data to Excel using JavaScript. I have tried to export table data with following JavaScript code

```
function ExportToExcel(){
        var htmltable= document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
   var html = htmltable.outerHTML;
   window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(html));
}
```

This code is working for a browser but for this application is not working.

```
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(html));
```

I think above line need to be change for native browser. Anyone could help me please. Thanks !

***Remark***:
the author is referring to a "Native Browser" which in his case is a browser control that is embedded inside of another desktop software product.

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate what "is not working" means in your case? Do you get a download window or nothing happens at all?

Comment: This is not a browser application so I'm not getting download window. If i put alert message then I'm getting all data. Thanks !

Comment: Could you add a bit more information regarding what you mean with "Native browser"? I was thinking of a native browser running on Android or other mobile rather than on a desktop application. I think that'll help to receive more relevant responses.

Comment: Sorry about confusion, its not actually native browser but look like nativebrowser apps. I have a desktop PC application and there I can add javascript, style etc... I can see the html page source. look like flash application with html.

Comment: Your application is a hybrid desktop app. Which is on top of ```Gecko browser engine```, the same thing behind firefox. However, you can execute javascript in that app console or inspect element just like firefox browser. But to download something from that application, your app have to have that functionality, like ```Choosing folder path``` etc. If you have that application source code than I think you can customize it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining but your setup is still not getting much clearer now. Which technology (.NET, Java, ...) do you use to wrap the browser control in it? Or do you use a proprietary application (e.g. bought software product) that comes along with embedded browser controls?

Comment: @Tamim Yes I have a function downloadAndSave(url), If I can keep all data in a url then I can download. Please suggest how can keep my data in a url. Thanks.

Comment: @SaschaM78 , It's a proprietary application (bought software product) that comes along with embedded browser controls.

Comment: In that case it'll be nearly impossible to help as we don't know how the software vendor implemented the browser control. Best would be to contact the vendor and ask how to achieve what you described in your question.

Comment: @SaschaM78 I have a function downloadAndSave(url) to download file. If I can save my data in a local folder using javascript then I can easily download data with function.There have any way save the file in a local folder using javascript ? Thanks !

Comment: Browsers are not allowed to access the local file system due to seurity concerns which also blocks Javascript being a part of the browser control from accessing local resources. There are things like the `LocalStorage` API that allow certain data to be written but it won't be accessible via a URL and I also doubt that this will be implemented as part of the software product.

Comment: @SaschaM78 could we keep data in a url or somewhere inside apps using javascript then call the url through  this downloadAndSave(url) function ? Thanks !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189262/discussion-between-sascham78-and-liton).

Answer (score 1):

This function works for me in Chrome, Firefox. I am not sure about IE or Edge.

```js
function ExportToExcel() {

  var htmltable = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
  if (window.chrome && !window.opr) {  // works for chrome
    var tableHtml = "<table border='1'>" + htmltable.innerHTML + "</table>";
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel' + ', ' + table_html;
    a.download = "abc.xls'; //setting the file name
    a.click();
  } else {

    var html = htmltable.outerHTML;
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(html));
  }
}
```

Comment: First thing I have no browser, this is a desktop application. your code is working for a web application but I need to download from desktop app. Thanks !